# What rule does this factors-of-a-polynomial question expect me to use?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, factoring

I came across this exam question:

> $f(x)=x^3+5x^2+px-q$
>
> Given that $(x+2)$ and $(x-1)$ are factors of $f(x)$,
>
> a) form a pair of simultaneous equations in $p$ and $q$
>
> b) show that $p=2$ and find the value of $q$

I immediately wrote, $f(x)=(x+2)(x-1)(x+\alpha) = x^3+5x^2+px-q$, expanded it and equated the coefficients. This answers the second part of the question directly, and given $p$ and $q$ I can construct simultaneous equations involving them arbitrarily.

What rule does the a) part of the question expect me use?

Comment: You can note that $f(-2)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: For the rule's name, it's called [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plug in the roots $x=-2$ and $x=1$ to get
$$
0=12-2p-q \\
0=6+p-q.
$$